# Force Haystack to index first letter of Charfield

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have a model with CharField()

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
   field = models.CharField(...)
```

How can I configure Haystack to index first letter of this field in SearchIndex?

```
class MyIndex(SearchIndex):
   starts_with = CharFiled(?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Haystack has something like Django`s forms clean functions which is called prepare.

So in my case to get first letter from field I can do:

class MyIndex(SearchIndex):
    starts_with = CharField()

```
def prepare_starts_with(self, obj):
    return obj.field[:1]
```